# Using standard library types as keys in QHash or QSet

Tags: c++, qt

Qt requires a `qHash` overload of the key type uses in Qt's `QHash` template. According to [the documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qhash.html#the-qhash-hashing-function) this overloads needs to be "in the type's namespace". But this is a problem because in c++ adding new overloads to the `std` namespace [is undefined behaviour](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std). Just adding the overload to the global namespace also does not work.

A minimal example:

```
#include <QHash>
#include <string>

//namespace std { // when adding to namespace std it compilies but that is not allowed
    static uint qHash(const std::u32string &key, uint seed) noexcept {
        return static_cast<uint>(std::hash<std::u32string>{}(key));
    }
//}

QHash<std::u32string, int> h;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    h.insert(std::u32string(), 5);
}
```

The generated error message is fairly long and i omitted the list of candidates that were tried (they did not contain the string overload)

```
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qglobal.h:83:0,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qcoreapplication.h:43,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/QCoreApplication:1,
                 from ../test.cpp:1:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qhashfunctions.h: In instantiation of ‘uint qHash(const T&, uint) [with T = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char32_t>; uint = unsigned int]’:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qhash.h:920:18:   required from ‘QHash<K, V>::Node** QHash<K, V>::findNode(const Key&, uint*) const [with Key = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char32_t>; T = int; QHash<K, V>::Node = QHashNode<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char32_t>, int>; uint = unsigned int]’
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qhash.h:760:27:   required from ‘QHash<K, V>::iterator QHash<K, V>::insert(const Key&, const T&) [with Key = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char32_t>; T = int]’
../qttui/testtui2.cpp:15:33:   required from here
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qhashfunctions.h:110:40: error: no matching function for call to ‘qHash(const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char32_t>&)’
     Q_DECL_NOEXCEPT_EXPR(noexcept(qHash(t)))
                                   ~~~~~^~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qcompilerdetection.h:1144:43: note: in definition of macro ‘Q_DECL_NOEXCEPT_EXPR’
 # define Q_DECL_NOEXCEPT_EXPR(x) noexcept(x)
                                           ^
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qlist.h:47:0,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qobject.h:49,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qcoreapplication.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/QCoreApplication:1,
                 from test.cpp:4,
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qhashfunctions.h:72:52: note: candidate: constexpr uint qHash(char, uint)
 Q_DECL_CONST_FUNCTION Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR inline uint qHash(char key, uint seed = 0) Q_DECL_NOTHROW { return uint(key) ^ seed; }
                                                    ^~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qhashfunctions.h:72:52: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char32_t>’ to ‘char’
```

The code in the error message is this (as far as i can tell in the global namespace):

```
template<typename T> inline uint qHash(const T &t, uint seed)
    Q_DECL_NOEXCEPT_EXPR(noexcept(qHash(t))) // <---- qhashfunctions.h:110
{ return qHash(t) ^ seed; }
```

and:

```
template <class Key, class T>
Q_OUTOFLINE_TEMPLATE typename QHash<Key, T>::Node **QHash<Key, T>::findNode(const Key &akey,                                                                           uint *ahp) const
{
    uint h = 0;

    if (d->numBuckets || ahp) {
        h = qHash(akey, d->seed); // <---- qhash.h:920
        if (ahp)
            *ahp = h;
    }
    return findNode(akey, h);
}
```

Comment: @AlexanderVX: I get the same error if i replace the body of the overload by `return 0;`

Answer (score 2):

Place the overload into the Qt namespace where the lookup is being done.

More specifically, it has to be injected into the namespace where the ADL-lookup attempt occurs.  This may involve tracking down what namespace the errors are happening in.

---

If you are designing a library and want to avoid this problem, you should create a namespace specifically to solve this problem.

Create two functions: `internal_qHash` and `qHash`.

```
namespace mylibrary {
  namespace hash_support {
    struct qhash_tag {};
    uint qHash( qhash_tag, int const& t, uint seed ) { /* TODO */ }
  }
  using ::mylibrary::hash_support::qhash_tag;
  template<class T>
  constexpr uint internal_qHash( T const& t, uint seed) {
    using ::mylibrary::hash_support::qHash;
    return qHash( qhash_tag{}, t, seed );
  }
  namespace hash_adl_blocking {
    template<class T>
    constexpr uint qHash( T const& t, uint seed ) {
      return ::mylibrary::internal_qHash( t, seed );
    }
  }
  using ::mylibrary::hash_adl_blocking::qHash;
}
```

now using `mylibrary::qHash` does an ADL based lookup with `mylibrary::hash_support` and any associated namespaces of `T`.

If we wanted SFINAE detection a tiny bit more work has to be done.

In this model, you'd create your overloads for namespaces you cannot inject functions into inside `namespace mylibrary::hash_support`.

It is possible that Qt is already doing something similar for `qHash(int, uint)`.  Look where Qt defines that, and if you define your `std` overloads there it should work.

The `qhash_tag` forces the 2-phase name lookup to reconsider new symbols injected into `mylibrary::hash_support` at the point `qHash` is instantiated for a given type.

Comment: This is a *qt* not a boost question ;). Qt doesn't use a namespace for it's api  by default. So as far as i can tell the usage attempt happens in the global namespace. Somehow it seems g++ sees the template at qhashfunctions.h:110 to be more specific than the overload it seems. (i'll add that code to the question too)

Comment: @textshell oops.  But replacing boost with Qt leaves the answer intact.  Look for where `qHash(int, uint)` is defined.

Comment: The problem is they are not defined in a namespace (i.e. at global level). The macro `QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE` is empty in a normal Qt install. Both existing definitions and the lookup happen in the global namespace. https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/tools/qhashfunctions.h.html So i don't even see where the ADL requirement comes from, because i would expect the usage to always try the global namespace too. It seems the template in qt (see edited question) is seen as more specific for some reason.

Comment: Ah.  Define your qHash before including any Qt headers.

Comment: Yes, indeed. That fixes the error. This seems to be one of the rare cases where wrong ordering does not yield a clean error. Sadly this solution breaks conventions about ordering of includes. But standard compliance overrules conventions of course. Thanks.